# jquery close div when click ouside

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am a bit new to jquery, I wanted to know if there is a simple way to close a div if one click out of it.

here's my HTML:

```
div#divlight {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
border: 2px solid #000000;
height: 600px;
left: 150px;
top: 10p;
padding: 15px;
position: absolute;
width: 800px;
overflow: scroll;
}
<body>
<div id="divlight">
</div>
</body>
```

And this is my JS

```
$(function(){
    $('#divlight').hide();
    }); 

    $("#show").click(function()
    {
        $("#divlight").show();
    });

    $("#hide").click(function()
    {
        $("#divlight").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure is, you can listen for all clicks, and if the target element is not within `#divlight`, close it

```
$(function(){
    $('#divlight').hide();

    $("#show").click(function() {
        $("#divlight").show();
    });

    $("#hide").click(function() {
        $("#divlight").hide();
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if ( ! $(e.target).closest("#divlight").length ) {
            $("#divlight").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `.stopPropagation()` event:

$(function(){

```
$('#divlight').hide();

// Stop click events from bubbling up to document
$("#show").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#divlight").show();
});

// Stop click events from bubbling up to document
$("#hide").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#divlight").hide();
});

// Bind click event to document
$(document).click(function(e) {
    $("#divlight").hide();
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I normally use `focusout` for that:

```
$('#divlight').on('focusout', function(){
   $(this).hide()
});
```

with the advantage of not needing to create a document click event